# What deployment approach does support fork tasks into pipelines and join them?

Tags: deployment, ansible, continuous-deployment

We are currently using Ansible not only for configuration management but also for deployments and we realised that Ansible architecture is not allowing us to perform different operations in parallel.

My impression is that Ansible will deploy only identical tasks in parallel but if you want to run big sets of different tasks in parallel, on the same machine or different machines you are out of luck.

I know that I could implement something like this using Jenkins pipelines but this would clearly be messy and very hard to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

2.x gives you the building blocks necessary to do this, since each host has a dynamic task list (instead of the single fixed task list shared by all hosts that gets built before execution in 1.x). You can likely get the behavior you want with various combinations of dynamic includes, the free execution strategy, and async with poll: 0 + async_status (depending on what exactly your needs are). Each are complex topics, so I won't elaborate further here unless you want to post a more specific use case.